# Notification from Google Play || Security vulnerabilities || Intent Redirection

Tags: android, android-security

I got this mail from Google, it says that "app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities" but nowhere it tells which package or library is causing the vulnerability.

On the google play console as well, I don't see details of this error anywhere.

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> We reviewed Dry Clean & Laundry - DhobiLite, with package name
> com.dhobilite, and found that your app uses software that contains
> security vulnerabilities for users. Apps with these vulnerabilities
> can expose user information or damage a user’s device, and may be
> considered to be in violation of our Malicious Behavior policy.
>
> Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that
> were detected in your recent submission. Please migrate your apps to
> use the updated software as soon as possible and increment the version
> number of the upgraded APK.
>
> [Unable to understand, what the issue is?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE91I.png)

Comment: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555?hl=en

Comment: Yes that is what I have written in the post that on the play console I don't see any alert but I get a mail every time I publish the app 

_This article says_
Sign in to your Play Console, and navigate to the Alerts section to see which apps are affected and the deadlines to resolve these issues.

Comment: I got the same mail have you found anything regarding this alerts tab in the new version of google play console? @DhobiLiteLaundry

Comment: @DhobiLiteLaundry Have you find the solution? we are in exactly same situation, no Alerts section, no deadline showing, we only got e-mails. Best.

Comment: @sourabhkarmakar what about you?